# How to display an image that is stored in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
   $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 2";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
   $result_set = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   echo $result_set['img'];
?>
```

Why do shows strange characters, not image?

Comment: a good reason not to store then in the db

Comment: So, why store your images in the database at all?  I know this does not answer your question, but 9 times out of 10, when someone is taking this approach, they really don't have a good reason for doing so.

Comment: You see strange characters because you are treating it like text; images are not text. You need to tell the browser what it is, using the [`Content-Type`](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) header.

Comment: Although it's rare to store images as blobs in databases, this certainly offers no clue as to why that might be a bad idea.

Comment: @Strawberry,  it's a bad idea because firstly, backup is going to be a pain. Secondly, as database size increases, you have the problem with database efficiency.

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly Interesting, and no doubt valid arguments - but not relevant to the OP's specific problem!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Content-Type header at the beginning, something like

```
<?
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
?>
```

for the PNG image